# how to creat a dictionary with tuple as a value from csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Can anyone tell me on how to create a dictionary from  CSV FILE in the following format(a tuple inside a dictionary)…. 
{ 'a' : (2.0,3.0), 'b' : (60.0 , 0.0), 'c': (100.0 , 0.0)}
the keys and the values are a ROWS in the csv file.

I tried this way, but all I am getting is a separate dictionaries instead of one dictionary. thanks

```
import csv
with open('Book1.csv') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in rdr:
        d={row[0]:(float(row[1]),float(row[2]))}

    print(d)
```

Comment: add your csv structure too.

Comment: Looks more like a JSON file. Impossible to answer with only a vague desription of the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a dictionary in each iteration, do this instead:

```
import csv

with open('Book1.csv') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    d = {row[0]: (float(row[1]), float(row[2])) for row in rdr}
    print(d)
```

Comment: Do u by any chance can help me to generate a NORMAL distribution of random of the above dictionary,  the final format must be in this way...     {'row[0]': row[1]}

Comment: @Bekry Glad I could aid. If my answer help you, please consider marking it as accepted. Regarding the normal distribution question, I think is best if you ask another question.